# How to attach xdebug to drush in docker

Tags: drush, debugging

How can I "attach" xdebug to drush in a docker container?

By that I mean, how can I have xdebug show me a history of an import script? And to look at the single variables that are defined and occupied during the import script?

The whole thing runs on: 
Docker version 2.1.05 (40693), Engine: 19.03.5, running on Mac 10.15.1.
Drupal version 8.7.9.
PhpStorm, Version 2019.3

My Config tempter, here the file docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  mariadb:
    image: wodby/mariadb:$MARIADB_TAG
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_mariadb"
    stop_grace_period: 30s
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $DB_ROOT_PASSWORD
      MYSQL_DATABASE: $DB_NAME
      MYSQL_USER: $DB_USER
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: $DB_PASSWORD
    ports:
      - "4306:3306"
  mysql:
    image: wodby/mariadb:$MARIADB_TAG
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_mariadb_test"
    stop_grace_period: 30s
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $DB_ROOT_PASSWORD
      MYSQL_DATABASE: $DB_NAME
      MYSQL_USER: $DB_USER
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: $DB_PASSWORD

  php:
    image: wodby/drupal-php:$PHP_TAG
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_php"
    environment:
      PHP_SENDMAIL_PATH: /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -S mailhog:1025
      DB_HOST: $DB_HOST
      DB_USER: $DB_USER
      DB_PASSWORD: $DB_PASSWORD
      DB_NAME: $DB_NAME
      DB_DRIVER: $DB_DRIVER
      PHP_FPM_USER: wodby
      PHP_FPM_GROUP: wodby
      COLUMNS: 80 # Set 80 columns for docker exec -it.

### From here the config of the Xdebug:
  PHP_XDEBUG: 1
      PHP_XDEBUG_DEFAULT_ENABLE: 1
      PHP_XDEBUG_REMOTE_AUTOSTART: 1
      PHP_XDEBUG_REMOTE_HOST: host.docker.internal # Docker 18.03+ Mac/Win
      PHP_IDE_CONFIG: serverName=Docker
      PHP_XDEBUG_REMOTE_CONNECT_BACK: 1
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html

 nginx:
  image: wodby/nginx:$NGINX_TAG
  container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_nginx"
  depends_on:
    - php
  environment:
    NGINX_STATIC_OPEN_FILE_CACHE: "off"
    NGINX_ERROR_LOG_LEVEL: debug
    NGINX_BACKEND_HOST: php
    NGINX_SERVER_ROOT: /var/www/html/docroot
    NGINX_VHOST_PRESET: $NGINX_VHOST_PRESET
  volumes:
    - ./:/var/www/html
  labels:
    - 'traefik.backend=${PROJECT_NAME}_nginx'
    - 'traefik.port=80'
    - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:${PROJECT_BASE_URL}'


 selenium-firefox:
  container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_firefox"
  image: selenium/standalone-firefox-debug:2.53.1
  volumes:
    # - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    - ./:/var/www/html
  ports:
    - "5905:5900"
    - "4444:4444"

 mailhog:
  image: mailhog/mailhog
  container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_mailhog"
  labels:
    - 'traefik.backend=${PROJECT_NAME}_mailhog'
    - 'traefik.port=8025'
    - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:mailhog.${PROJECT_BASE_URL}'

memcached:
  container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_memcached"
  image: wodby/memcached:$MEMCACHED_TAG
  command: "sh -c 'memcached -m 1024'"


portainer:
  image: portainer/portainer
  container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_portainer"
  command: --no-auth -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
  volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
  labels:
    - 'traefik.backend=${PROJECT_NAME}_portainer'
    - 'traefik.port=9000'
    - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:portainer.${PROJECT_BASE_URL}'

traefik:
  image: traefik:v1.7-alpine
  container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_traefik"
  command: -c /dev/null --web --docker --logLevel=INFO
  ports:
    - '80:80'
  volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

 php_test:
  container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_php_test"
  image: registry.my_projekt.de/drupal-test
  volumes:
    - ./:/var/www/html
  environment:
    CI_PROJECT_DIR : "/var/www/html/"
    DATABASE_PATH: "/root/database.sql"
    SELENIUM_PORT: "4444"
    BROWSER: "firefox"
    WEB_DRIVE: ""
    DISPLAY: ":99"
    UPDATE_ALIAS: "myProjekt:update"
    DB_HOST: 'mysql'
  labels:
    - 'traefik.port=80'
    - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:test.${PROJECT_BASE_URL}'

 php_quality:
  image: hussainweb/drupal-code-quality:latest
  command: tail -f /dev/null
  volumes:
    - ./:/var/www/html
```

Comment: You should add what IDE are you using (vi, Netbeans, Eclipse, PhpStorm, etc).

Comment: oh, sorry, I forgot, PhpStorm, Version 2019.3

Answer (score 1):

It can happen if you are using drush launcher (https://github.com/drush-ops/drush-launcher). This tool allows you to type "drush" in your Drupal directory, instead of "./vendor/bin/drush", but it can confuse xdebug. 
Using "./vendor/bin/drush" may fix the problem.

Additionally, you may also have to set an environment variable in your PHP container:

`export PHP_IDE_CONFIG="serverName=my_server"`

... where my_server is the name of the server in

`Preferences / Languages & Frameworks / PHP / Servers`

where your path mapping is set in PHP storm.

You may also wish to enable the option: "Break at first line in PHP scripts" and then run your drush commands - as often it can be tricky to set breakpoints in the correct place when running drush.